# How to set lookahead threads in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

In handbrake I set threads=18 lookahead_threads=3. I have switched to FFMPEG and I can't find an option for lookahead threads and I am only get 1 unless I go all the way up to 24 threads then it defaults to 2. How can I set lookahead threads in FFMPEG? I have looked everywhere for the answer but I can't find it.

Comment: Why do you want to modify this? It should automatically choose an optimal value. And you shouldn't be manually setting threads either. libx264 will auto that too (assuming that's the encoder you're using).

Comment: I am encoding on multiple computers and I want the threading to be the same on all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone has this question, one answer is

-x264-params no-fast-pskip=1:lookahead -threads=3

pskip parameter is not required, I just wanted to include a multi parameter example

I think there is another answer, something to do with loop but this works so please add to this solution if you have a more pure solution.